# skipping vector position when pushing_back

Tags: c++, vector, string

I'm reading data from a file into a vector of strings called `data`. And to this data vector I push_back a new string through my main called `output_string`. Output_string is just a combination of the arguments passed in through command line. After doing all that I write back to my file(update the file with the new string). However when I do this, everything after the 1st command line argument,it skips a vector position whenever it encounters `data.push_back(output_string);` again.

*eg file contents*

```
bob
jack
snack
```

after reading into vector,

*data vector contents*

```
bob
jack
snack
```

*after adding new string, new string being "john" data vector contents become*

```
bob
jack
snack
john
```

but if i Run the program again and use command line to add something again it skips one vector position

```
bob
jack
snack
john

peter
```

and it does this for everything that I add after the first. Why is doing this?

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){


 if (argc > 6){
  cout<<"[Error] too many inputs provided" << endl;
  return 0;
 }

 commandProcess(argc,argv);

 outputstringformat();
 //*********
 if (cominput.rem_contpos == -1){
  readData();                        //reads data from a file into vector data
  int outlen = output_string.length();
  if (outlen > 0){
   data.push_back(output_string);  //pushing what i had in argv to vector
  }

  cout<<"----------data vector------------"<<endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < data.size();i++){
   cout<<"data: " << data[i] << endl;
  }

  ofstream outfile("contactlist.dat");
  number_of_contacts = data.size();
  if(outfile.is_open()){
   for (int i =0; i < number_of_contacts; i++){
    outfile << data[i] << endl; //copying evertthing back to file, including the new argument passed to data
   }
   outfile.close();
  }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**
also this is how I process my arguments, I combine them into a single string. I have an inkling this could be the issue but still don't see it... :|

```
void outputstringformat(){

    if (cominput.name1.length() != 0 ){
        output_string = cominput.name1;
    }   
    if (cominput.name2.length() != 0 ){
        output_string = output_string + " " + cominput.name2;
    }
    if (cominput.name3.length() != 0 ){
        output_string = output_string + " " + cominput.name3;
    }
    if (cominput.email.length() != 0 ){
        output_string = output_string + " " + cominput.email;
    }
    if (cominput.phone.length() != 0 ){
        output_string = output_string + " " + cominput.phone;
    }
}
```

**updated with reaData**

```
void readData(){
    ifstream myfile("contactlist.dat");
    if(myfile.is_open()){
        while(!myfile.eof()){
            getline(myfile,line);
            data.push_back(line);
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What might be happening is that originally, the file contents are the string:

```
"bob\n"
"jack\n"
"snack" // no line feed
```

which, line-by-line, is "bob", "jack", and "snack". When you write out these lines along with "john" `endl`, the contents of the file are:

```
"bob\n"
"jack\n"
"snack\n"
"john\n" // line feed
```

You might be reading this as "bob", "jack", "snack", "john", and "" because after "john\n" has been read, the end-of-file has technically not been reached yet, but it will be reached upon the next attempt to read.

**EDIT:** This `readData` will probably work for you:

```
void readData() {
    ifstream myfile("contactlist.dat");
    if(myfile.is_open()){
        string l;
        while(myfile >> l){
            data.push_back(l);
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
}
```

As demonstrated at http://codepad.org/INgm757m, this version will have the same behavior regardless of whether the last character in `contactlist.dat` is a line feed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem:

```
while(!myfile.eof()){
    getline(myfile,line);
    data.push_back(line);
}
```

`myfile.eof()` will only be true *after* you have attempted to read beyond the end of the file; it does not tell you whether or not the next read will reach EOF. So your last `getline` will not read anything (due to EOF), yet you will put the empty `line` string into the vector anyway.

The correct way to write this loop is simply:

```
while(getline(myfile,line)) {
    data.push_back(line);
}
```

This works because the return value of `getline` is the stream that was read from (`myfile`, in this case), and iostreams are designed so that when used in a test, such as `if (myfile)`, they evaluate to true if and only if neither an error nor an EOF has been encountered. Written this way, when EOF is reached, `getline` will return `myfile` which will evaluate to false in the while test, and so the line will not be pushed into the vector.

This method also has the advantage of stopping the file read on errors other than EOF.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really enough to go on here, but I suspect that `readData()` is adding an empty string to the vector. Try this:

```
// Put this right after readData()
cout<<"----------data vector from file------------"<<endl;
for (int i = 0; i < data.size();i++){
  cout<<"data[" << i << "]: " << data[i] << endl;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I'm not familiar with your version of `getline`, but it look as if it's picking up the final CR or LF or whatever. Try this:

```
void readData(){
    ifstream myfile("contactlist.dat");
    if(myfile.is_open()){
        while(!myfile.eof()){
            getline(myfile,line);
            if(myfile.gcount()>0){  // checking for zero-length string
                data.push_back(line);
            }
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: you are right... could you tell me whats wrong here?

void readData(){
 ifstream myfile("contactlist.dat");
 if(myfile.is_open()){
  while(!myfile.eof()){
   getline(myfile,line);
   data.push_back(line);
  }
  myfile.close();
 }
}